# Indexing ng-repeat to only edit one

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to index my ng-repeat so that I can edit a row by making the one with text disappear and the one with inputs appear.

```
    <div ng-controller="BusinessGoalsCtrl">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>Type:</th>
                    <th>Timeframe:</th>
                    <th>Goal:</th>
                    <th>Edit:</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-class="editMode ? 'ng-hide' : ''" ng-repeat="details in businessGoalDetails track by $index">
                    <td style="width:30%;">{{details.display_name}} {{$index}}</td>
                    <td style="width:30%;">{{details.timeframe}}</td>
                    <td style="width:30%;">{{details.threshold}}</td>
                    <td style="width:10%;"><i ng-click="toggleEdit(true, $index)" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-class="editMode ? '' : 'ng-hide'" ng-repeat="inputs in businessGoalDetails track by $index">
                    <td style="width:30%;"><input ng-model="inputs.display_name"/></td>
                    <td style="width:30%;"><input ng-model="inputs.timeframe"/></td>
                    <td style="width:30%;"><input ng-model="inputs.threshold"/></td>
                    <td style="width:10%;"><i ng-click="toggleEdit(false, $index)" class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Angular Code

```
$scope.editMode = false;
        $scope.details = 0;
        $scope.toggleEdit = function (showEdit, $index) {
            console.log("editing view");
            $scope.editMode = showEdit;
        }
```

Comment: You should look up docs on ng-class and ng-hide, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: [Can you just use this](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row) ? Some projects do not let you use external libraries but really this will prevent you from re-inventing the wheel and give you more features.

Comment: You should just use ng-if or ng-show instead of ng-class, are you trying to edit all rows or just one?

Comment: What is your problem or question?

Comment: I recommend you to use a modal instead of in-table inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just use `ng-if/ng-show` instead of `ng-class` and use `ng-repeat-start/end` instead of creating 2 different ng-repeats. Also you could just make a single row editable by setting property on its child scope or on the object under iteration. In your code you are setting the property `editMode` at the parent scope level and not only that it is not specific to each row.

```
<tr ng-show="!details.editMode" ng-repeat-start="details in businessGoalDetails track by $index">
    <!-- ... -->
    <td style="width:10%;"><i ng-click="details.editMode=true" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></td>
</tr>
<tr ng-show="details.editMode" ng-repeat-end>
    <td style="width:30%;"><input ng-model="details.display_name"/></td>
    <!-- ... -->
    <td style="width:10%;"><i ng-click="details.editMode=false" class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
</tr>
```

Or

```
<tr ng-show="!editMode" ng-repeat-start="details in businessGoalDetails track by $index">
    <!-- ... -->
    <td style="width:10%;"><i ng-click="toggleEdit(true)" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></td>
</tr>
<tr ng-show="editMode" ng-repeat-end>
    <td style="width:30%;"><input ng-model="details.display_name"/></td>
    <!-- ... -->
    <td style="width:10%;"><i ng-click="toggleEdit(false)" class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
</tr>
```

and

```
    $scope.toggleEdit = function (showEdit) {
        this.editMode = showEdit; //'this' here is the child scope
    }
```